# Shiny button doesn't work when I click it. Can sb help me?

Tags: r, button, plot, shiny

I want to  add 3 different buttons to show different plot but use the same input information.

But now I was trapped in the first step.
when I click the first button which is linked to the first plot but it didn't work.

Can somebody help me to deal with it. Thanks a lot.

Here is my sample code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#####
mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

# Prepare dataset.
#   1. Bind mean and sd data
#   2. Reshape
data <- bind_rows(list(
  mean = mean_data,
  sd = sd_data
), .id = "stat")
data_mean_sd <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Name, stat), names_to = "Gene", values_to = "value") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "stat", values_from = "value")
###
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           h2("Gene_FPKM Value Barplot")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           selectInput(
             "selectGeneSymbol", 
             "Select Gene Symbol:", 
             choices = unique(data_mean_sd$Gene),
             multiple =F,
             width = 800,
             selected = "Igfbp7"
           ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           actionButton(inputId = "FPKM", label = "FPKM"),
           actionButton(inputId = "logFC", label = "logFC"),
           actionButton(inputId = "logFC&FPKM",label = "logFC&FPKM")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,align="center",
           plotOutput(outputId = "barplot1",height = 700, width = 1300)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,align="center",
           plotOutput(outputId = "barplot2",height = 700, width = 1300)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data_FPKM <- eventReactive(input$FPKM, {
    plot_data <- reactive({
      subset(data_mean_sd, Gene %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
    })
    ggplot(data = plot_data(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$GeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12))
  })  ##  建立 按钮与 数据的关系
  
  output$barplot <- renderPlot(
    {
      barplot(data_FPKM())
    }) 
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Who can help me to find where the wrong with my code. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to get output for the 1st plot on click of 1st button. You can use the same process for other plots.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

# Prepare dataset.
#   1. Bind mean and sd data
#   2. Reshape
data <- bind_rows(list(
  mean = mean_data,
  sd = sd_data
), .id = "stat")
data_mean_sd <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Name, stat), names_to = "Gene", values_to = "value") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "stat", values_from = "value")
###
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           h2("Gene_FPKM Value Barplot")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           selectInput(
             "selectGeneSymbol", 
             "Select Gene Symbol:", 
             choices = unique(data_mean_sd$Gene),
             multiple =F,
             width = 800,
             selected = "Igfbp7"
           ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           actionButton(inputId = "FPKM", label = "FPKM"),
           actionButton(inputId = "logFC", label = "logFC"),
           actionButton(inputId = "logFC&FPKM",label = "logFC&FPKM")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,align="center",
           plotOutput(outputId = "barplot1",height = 700, width = 1300)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,align="center",
           plotOutput(outputId = "barplot2",height = 700, width = 1300)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  plot_data <- reactive({
    subset(data_mean_sd, Gene %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
  })
  
  v <- reactiveValues(barplot1 = NULL,barplot2 = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$FPKM, {
    ggplot(data = plot_data(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$GeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12)) -> v$barplot1
  })  
  
  output$barplot1 <- renderPlot({
    v$barplot1
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Vary thankful !!  I got it and I have finished the second plot.

But I have a small question is that I want to show the first and second plot respectively.

I mean when the first or the second plot appears, the another one will disappear. 
And each of them shows on the same place. 

But if  someone clicks the third button(logFC&FPKM)，the two plots show in turn on the first and second place  ??  

Can you give me some advice ?

Comment: Try to override `v$barplot1` at every click so that whenever you click a button you have the latest plot. If you face trouble implementing this you can ask a new question.